# Get the inner HTML of a element in lxml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get the HTML content of child node with lxml and xpath in Python. As shown in code below, I want to find the html content of the each of product nodes. Does it have any methods like product.html?

```py
productGrids = tree.xpath("//div[@class='name']/parent::*")
for product in productGrids:
    print #html content of product
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree
print(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

you may see more examples here: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Comment: Remember it has a optional parameter `encode` use like this: `etree.tostring(xxxxx, encoding='unicode')`

Comment: That's *outer* HTML.

Comment: I juts get `TypeError: Type 'list' cannot be serialized.`

Answer (score 17):

I believe you want to use the `tostring()` method:

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring('<html><head><title>foo</title></head><body><div class="name"><p>foo</p></div><div class="name"><ul><li>bar</li></ul></div></body></html>')
for elem in tree.xpath("//div[@class='name']"):
     # pretty_print ensures that it is nicely formatted.
     print etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function to get **innerHTML or innerXML**

Try it out directly https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/631aa049-2785-4c58-bf82-eff4e2f8bedb/

**function**

```py
def innerXML(elem):
    elemName = elem.xpath('name(/*)')
    resultStr = ''
    for e in elem.xpath('/'+ elemName + '/node()'):
        if(isinstance(e, str) ):
            resultStr = resultStr + ''
        else:
            resultStr = resultStr + etree.tostring(e, encoding='unicode')

    return resultStr
```

**invocation**

```py
XMLElem = etree.fromstring("<div>I am<name>Jhon <last.name> Corner</last.name></name>.I work as <job>software engineer</job><end meta='bio' />.</div>")
print(innerXML(XMLElem))
```

**Logic Behind**

- Get the outermost element name first,
- Then get all the child nodes
- Convert all the child nodes to string using `tostring`
- Concanate them

Answer (score -1):

After right clicking (copy, copy xpath) on the specific field you want (in chrome's inspector), you might get something like this:

```
//*[@id="specialID"]/div[12]/div[2]/h4/text()[1]
```

If you wanted that text element for each "specialID"

```
//*[@id="specialID"]/div/div[2]/h4/text()[1]
```

You could select another field and it'll interleave the results

```
//*[@id="specialID"]/div/div[2]/h4/text()[1] | //*[@id="specialID"]/div/some/weird/path[95]
```

Example could be improved, but it illustrates the point:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul[1]/li[11]/text()
```

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
data = tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul[1]/li/a/text() | //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/ul[1]/li/text()[1]')
print(len(data))
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(data[i])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `product.text_content()` if what you are looking for is the text content rather than the HTML.

Comment: based on lxml [documentation](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) `.text_content()` method returns the text content of the element and **not** the inner HTML

Comment: While the answer was not technically correct, it solved my problem, because that is what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do this

```py
x=doc.xpath("//div[@class='name']/parent::*")
print(map(etree.tostring,x))
```