# Trouble clicking on the button for the next page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium. I intended to parse the table from a webpage. I've got it working. However, trouble comes up when i try to click on the next page button. The scraper only parse the table from the first page and instead of clicking the next button it quits without throwing any error. So, i can't understand what I'm missing.

Here is the full code for your consideration:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://toolkit.financialexpress.net/santanderam")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.fe-datatable')))

tab_data = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.fe-datatable')

while True:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr')))
    list_rows = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')]
                 for row in tab_data.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')]
    for data in list_rows:
        print(data)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.ui-paging-next').click()
    except:
        break

driver.quit()
```

Elements within which the next-page button exists:

```
<div class="pagination ui-widget"><span class="ui-paging-current ui-state-default ui-state-disabled ui-corner-all ui-paging-prev">Prev</span><span class="ui-paging-current ui-state-default ui-state-disabled ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">1</span><a class="ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">2</a><a class="ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">3</a><a class="ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#">4</a><span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled ui-paging-ellipse">...</span><a class="ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all ep" href="#">7</a><a class="ui-paging-button ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-paging-next" href="#">Next</a></div>
```

Comment: Try driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class*='ui-paging-next']").click() or find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()

Comment: Thanks  Grasshopper, for you answer. It didn't do the trick with css selector but it seems to be working with link text. 'll get back to you after testing. Thanks.

Comment: It does click on the link but throws another error. "    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Comment: @SMth80, On which line you get the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Grasshopper has already provided with a solution, but I'll try to give more details for you to understand why your code fails

There are two links with the same `HTML` code present in page source: the first is hidden, second (the one that you need) is not.

You can check it with

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.ui-paging-next')))
```

While css-selector or XPath returns you simply the first occurence, search by link text returns link with the visible text only:

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Next')))
```

That's why your `find_element_by_css_selector(...)` code doesn't work, but `find_element_by_link_text(...)` does.

Also note that line

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.fe-datatable')))
```

should already return you required element, so there is no need in

```
tab_data = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.fe-datatable')
```

Just use

```
tab_data = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.fe-datatable')))
```

To avoid getting `StaleElementReferenceException` you should re-define your `tab_data` on each iterarion as `tab_data` defined on first page will not be accessible on the next page. Just put `tab_data` definition inside the `while` loop

*UPDATE*

In your code try to replace

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
except:
    break
```

with

```
first_row = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.fe-datatable tr.odd').text
try:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
except:
    break
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.fe-datatable tr.odd').text != first_row)
```

Comment: I'm getting that error in line 192 and in my script just before "for data in list_rows:". FYI, before executing the script i took that tab_data inside loop. I'm giving a link with my rectified code in it in a while. Thanks sir.

Comment: This the the script 'm trying with now: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw71wircwbj5zv8/Rectified%20One.txt?dl=0"

Comment: You are invincible sir Andersson. Perfect as always. Can you give a oneliner explanation to make me understand what you did up there? Thanks again for you flawless solution.

Comment: When you click "Next" button you just send new XHR, so page is not actually completelly reloaded, but table only. You see that spiner (loader) appears and you need to wait until it disappeared and new data loaded, but selenium tries to search table right after the click and doesn't wait for table update. So it returns you the same not yet re-loaded `table`. I added lines that allows you to wait until text from first row is updated (not equal to the previous value). It's not the best solution, I guess, but it should work

Comment: Sir Andersson, when you have time to spare, you can track down this link: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401274/how-can-i-activate-each-item-and-parse-their-information" Thanks in advance.