# How can I activate each item and parse their information?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I came across a different type of problem while scraping a webpage using python. When an image is clicked, new information concerning its' flavor comes up under the image. My goal is to parse all the flavors connected to each image. My script can parse the flavors of currently active image but breaks after clicking on the new image. A little twitch in my loop will lead me to the right direction.

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='colright']//ul[@class='opt2']//label")))
    for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='colright']//ul[@class='opt2']//label"):
        print(item.text)

    try:
        links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='img']/img")
        for link in links:
            link.click()
    except:
        break

driver.quit()
```

The picture underneath may clarify what i could not:

[image]

Comment: Some tips: to get required data you need to send POST to https://www.optigura.com/product/ajax/details.php. `data` should contain next keys `'opt', 'opt1', 'opt2', 'ip'`. Value for 'opt' parameter should be `flavor`. To get `ip` you need to find element `<div class="options1 custom-radio" data-ip="105">` and get `data-ip`. It should be common for each item. `opt1` is unique for each item. You can find it in `<input name="is" value="145" type="radio">`- the `value` attribute. `opt2` can be found in `<input name="ipr" data-opt-sel="506" checked="checked" type="radio">`- `data-opt-sel` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweaked the code to properly click on the links and to check if the current listed item's text matches with the active listed item's text. If they match, you can safely go on parsing without worrying that you are parsing the same thing over and over again. Here you go:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.optigura.com/uk/product/gold-standard-100-whey/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='img']/img")

for idx, link in enumerate(links):
    while True:
        try:
            link.click()
            while driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='size']")[idx].text != driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='colright']//li[@class='active']//span")[1].text:
                link.click()
            print driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='size']")[idx].text
            items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='colright']//ul[@class='opt2']//label")))
            for item in items.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='colright']//ul[@class='opt2']//label"):
            print(item.text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue
        break
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Tehscript for you answer. After scraping two items (two categories) it throws an error: "line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" . Btw, I have done the same with vba as well.
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404511/scraping-html-with-selenium-while-clicking-options/45404708#45404708"

Comment: @SMth80 I tried and tested the code, never had any issues. Well then if it raises exception, you know you can always catch it. Please see the edited code.

Comment: Your updated and earlier code are doing just awesome. When I ran for the third time and so on, you earlier code is working great as well. Thanks for you time and everything.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it has much to do with Python, just many Javascript and ajax things.

[image]

The javascript part is

```
$(document).on("click", ".product-details .custom-radio input:not(.active input)", function() {
    var elm = $(this);
    var root = elm.closest(".product-details");
    var option = elm.closest(".custom-radio");
    var opt, opt1, opt2, ip, ipr;
    elm.closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
    elm.closest("li").addClass("active");
    if (option.hasClass("options1")) {
        ip = root.find(".options1").data("ip");
        opt = root.find(".options2").data("opt");
        opt1 = root.find(".options1 li.active input").val();
        opt2 = root.find(".options2 li.active input").data("opt-sel");
    } else
        ipr = root.find(".options2 input:checked").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/product/ajax/details.php",
        data: {
            opt: opt,
            opt1: opt1,
            opt2: opt2,
            ip: ip,
            ipr: ipr
        },
```

So you can just construct the params(use css selector will be better than xpath in this case), post and parse the json results.