# IndexError: list index out of range while using aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-scraping

When I ran this code on Jupyter and Virtual Machine, it ran smoothly. But when I started running in on AWS, it always shows **list index out of range**. I would like to know how to fix this problem. Thanks!

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import strptime
import requests
from lxml import html
import re
import time
import os
import sys

from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text as sa_text
import pymysql


date_list=[]
for i in range(0,2):
    duration=datetime.today() - timedelta(days=i)
    forma=duration.strftime("%m-%d")
    date_list.append(forma)

print(date_list)



def curl_topic_url_hot():
    url = 'https://www.xxxx.com/topiclist.php?f=397&p=1'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    output = tree.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']/a[7]")
    maxPage = int(output[0].text)
    print('There are', maxPage, 'pages.')

    return [maxPage]

topic_url_hot = curl_topic_url_hot()
```

AWS log:

```
['02-12', '02-11']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/ellen_crawl/test0211_mobile.py", line 167, in <module>
    topic_url_hot = curl_topic_url_hot()
  File "/home/hadoop/ellen_crawl/test0211_mobile.py", line 48, in curl_topic_url_hot
    maxPage = int(output[0].text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I ran this code on Jupyter, it shows:

```
['02-12', '02-11']
There are 818 pages.
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner when I try to print tree, it shows <Element html at 0x7f28bd940bd8>

Answer (score 3):

You could either use

```
if len(output) > 1:
    maxPage = int(output[0].text)
```

Or

```
try:
    maxPage = int(output[0].text)
except IndexError:
    # do sth. with the error message
```

In either case, your original code does not produce the result you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the error by testing first and only indexing into your result or by try/except-catching the error:

```
if len(output)>0: 
    maxPage = int(output[0].text)
```

---

```
try:
    maxPage = int(output[0].text)
except IndexError as e:
    pass # log it or do smth with it
```

---

Your **real problem** lies elsewhere:

Your curling does not produce what you think it does - maybe AWS does not support what you want to do and hence the request is blocked and returns nothing? Maybe you have a typo in your url?

Some ideas:

- inspect the content of `tree`
- inspect your aws logs.
- inspect the `response` for its errorcode
- try the url manually (you did that, this is more for others that find this later on)

Comment: It prints nothing if I do try except, probably I should try it with beautifulsoup!

Comment: @Lara have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14896505/7505395 - this could help you get to the content you want (not an answer to this question though :o)

Answer (score -2):

Your AWS visit this website and it return error html, check it.
https://www.xxxx.com/topiclist.php?f=397&p=1

Comment: do you really think that www.xxxx.com is the _real_ url used here?

Comment: Of course not, You can your aws log and print the html result.

Comment: Lara has given only example url. not the actual URL @DivideBy0

Comment: The OP obfuscated the URL she is using - the obfuscated URL does not lead to a valid target so it throws an error. Your answer based on that error does not make sense.

Comment: What i mean is check the html result, not the url