# Python, lxml.html: Need a generic funtion to return innerhtml of any element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml.html

I found a nice function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896302/get-the-inner-html-of-a-element-in-lxml) by Siva Kannan but its not working in my case.  I'm using lxml.html to get the data from the page and not etree.  When I use etree I get the exception:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name
```

Below is his example modified to first get data from a yellowpages page, then attempt to get innerhtml from a specific div tag

Any help would be great and should help a many people.

Thank you

```
from lxml import etree
import requests, time, socket
import lxml.html as lxml

def innerXML(elem):
    elemName = elem.xpath('name(/*)')
    resultStr = ''
    for e in elem.xpath('/'+ elemName + '/node()'):
        if(isinstance(e, str) ):
            resultStr = resultStr + ''
        else:
            resultStr = resultStr + etree.tostring(e, encoding='unicode')

    return resultStr

# This works nicely but for my data
# XMLElem = etree.fromstring("<div>I am<xxxxxx>Jhon <last.xxxxx> Corner</last.xxxxx></xxxxxx>.I    work as <job>software engineer</job><end meta='bio' />.</div>")
# print(innerXML(XMLElem))

response = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/washington-dc/mip/bnsf-railway-496598824')
data = response.text
# The next line is how I need to get data for all my work.
# tree = lxml.fromstring(data)

# Siva Kannan's way
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
div_node = tree.xpath("//dd[@class='open-hours']")
# div_node = tree.xpath("//dd[@class='open-hours']//div")  # When using lxml.fromstring (my normal    code) this returns a list when using 

div_html = innerXML(div_node)
print(div_html)
```

Comment: Just don't switch to `lxml.etree` because often HTML can't be parsed using XML parser. Keep your `tree` definition to be: `tree = lxml.fromstring(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Erase `from lxml import etree`, replace `etree.tostring` with `lxml.tostring`, and replace `etree.fromstring` with `lxml.fromstring`.

As a side note, this code will also produce an error because `div_node` will be a list of nodes rather than a node, but that should be easy to fix.